# Error "javax.persistence.PersistenceException Type xxx is not found (error 301)" while using ObjectDB (Java)

Tags: java, objectdb

I'm working with ObjectDB at school, and, while doing homework I had a problem.

There is the problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" [ObjectDB 2.8.7] DELETE FROM  ==> Jugador <== 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException
Type Jugador is not found (error 301)
 (position 12)  at com.objectdb.jpa.JpaQuery.executeUpdate(JpaQuery.java:805)
    at com.mycompany.objectdb.NewMain.eliminarDatos(NewMain.java:89)
    at com.mycompany.objectdb.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:38)
Caused by: com.objectdb.o.TEX: Type Jugador is not found
    at com.objectdb.o.MSG.b(MSG.java:110)
    at com.objectdb.o.TRS.b(TRS.java:214)
    at com.objectdb.o.SYR.g(SYR.java:261)
    at com.objectdb.o.SYR.f(SYR.java:190)
    at com.objectdb.o.QRC.<init>(QRC.java:158)
    at com.objectdb.o.QRM.Z1(QRM.java:272)
    at com.objectdb.o.MST.Z1(MST.java:1026)
    at com.objectdb.o.WRA.Z1(WRA.java:313)
    at com.objectdb.o.WSM.Z1(WSM.java:117)
    at com.objectdb.o.QRR.k(QRR.java:260)
    at com.objectdb.o.QRR.i(QRR.java:154)
    at com.objectdb.jpa.JpaQuery.executeUpdate(JpaQuery.java:791)
    ... 2 more
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is my Main and my class "Jugador", which is reference that is doesn't exist.

> package com.mycompany.objectdb;
>
> import javax.persistence.*; import java.util.*; import
> java.text.ParseException; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import
> java.util.logging.Level; import java.util.logging.Logger;
>
> public class NewMain {
>
> ```
> public static EntityManagerFactory emf;
> public static EntityManager em;
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>     int opcion = -1;
>     int opcion3 = -1;
>     
>     while (opcion != 0) {
>         System.out.println("0. Cerrar aplicación");
>         System.out.println("1. Conexión a BBDD");
>         System.out.println("2. Reiniciar datos");
>         System.out.println("3. Aplicacion");
>         System.out.println("");
>         try {
>             System.out.println("¿Qué desea hacer?");
>             opcion = in.nextInt();
>             System.out.println("");
>             
>             switch (opcion) {
>                 case 0:
>                     break;
>                 case 1:
>                     inicializaFactory();
>                     break;
>                 case 2:
>                     inicializaFactory();
>                     eliminarDatos(em);
>                     reiniciarDatos(em);
>                 case 3:
>                     System.out.println("Has elegido aplicación");
>                     System.out.println("Selecciona lo que desea hacer");
>                     System.out.println("1. Insertar objeto");
>                     System.out.println("2. Modificar objeto");
>                     System.out.println("3. Borrar objeto");
>                     System.out.println("4. Realizar consulta");
>                     opcion3 = in.nextInt();
>                         if (opcion3== 1) {
>                             inicializaFactory();
>                             Expulsion2OP2.insJPQLT2(em);
>                         } else if (opcion3 == 2) {
>                             inicializaFactory();
>                             Expulsion2OP2.modifJPQLT2(em);
>                         } else if (opcion3 == 3) {
>                             inicializaFactory();
>                             Expulsion2OP2.borradoJPTLT2(em);
>                         } else if (opcion3 == 4) {
>                             inicializaFactory();
>                             Expulsion2OP2.consultaJPTLT2(em);
>                         } else {
>                             System.out.println("No existe ningún método asignado a ese número");
>                             opcion3 = in.nextInt();
>                         }
>                     
>                 break;
>                 
>                 default:
>                 System.out.println("Escribe un número entre el 0 y el 3");
>             }
>         } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
>             System.out.println("Inserta un valor válido");
>             in.next();
>         }
>   }
>     if (em != null){
>         em.close();
>         emf.close();
>     }
> }
> public static void inicializaFactory(){
>     emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("./db/proyecto.odb");
>     em=emf.createEntityManager();
>     System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
>     System.out.println("");
> }
> public static void eliminarDatos(EntityManager em){
>     // Eliminar
>     em.getTransaction().begin();
>     em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Jugador").executeUpdate();
>     em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Partido").executeUpdate();
>     em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Expulsion").executeUpdate();
>     em.getTransaction().commit();
>     System.out.println("");
>     System.out.println("Datos eliminados con éxito");
> }
> public static void reiniciarDatos(EntityManager em){
>     //Crear
>     em.getTransaction().begin();
>     Jugador j1 = new Jugador("8","Griezmann","Atlético de Madrid","8","Delantero");
>             em.persist(j1);
>     Jugador j2 = new Jugador("23","Pedri","F.C Barcelona","16","Delantero");
>             em.persist(j2);
>     Jugador j3 = new Jugador("55","Pau Torres","Villarreal","4","Defensa");  
>             em.persist(j3);
>     Partido p1 = new Partido("442","Atlético de Madrid","Osasuna","Semifinal Copa del Rey","Wanda Metropolitano");
>             em.persist(p1);
>     Partido p2 = new Partido("452","F.C Barcelona","Betis","Jornada 8 Liga","Camp Nou");
>             em.persist(p2);
>     Partido p3 = new Partido("447","Sevilla","Villarreal","Jornada 11 Liga","Sanchez Pizjuan");
>             em.persist(p3);
>     Expulsion e1 = new Expulsion("120","28","Patada en el tobillo",j1,p1);
>             em.persist(e1);
>     Expulsion e2 = new Expulsion("124","88","Falta por detrás",j2,p2);
>             em.persist(e2);
>     Expulsion e3 = new Expulsion("126","41","Cabezazo en el pecho",j3,p3);
>             em.persist(e3);
>     em.getTransaction().commit();
>     System.out.println("Los datos han sido reiniciados con éxito");
> }
>
>  }
> ```

Jugador

> package com.mycompany.objectdb;
>
> import java.io.Serializable; import javax.persistence.Basic; import
> javax.persistence.Column; import javax.persistence.Entity; import
> javax.persistence.Id;
>
> @Entity
>
> public class Jugador implements Serializable {
>
> ```
> private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
> @Id
> @Basic(optional = false)
> @Column(name = "IDJUGADOR")
> private String idjugador;
> @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
> private String nombre;
> @Column(name = "EQUIPO")
> private String equipo;
> @Column(name = "DORSAL")
> private String dorsal;
> @Column(name = "POSICION")
> private String posicion;
>
> public Jugador() {
>     
> }
>
> public Jugador(String idjugador){
>     this.idjugador = idjugador;
> }
>
> public Jugador(String idjugador, String nombre, String equipo, String dorsal, String posicion) {
>     this.idjugador = idjugador;
>     this.nombre = nombre;
>     this.equipo = equipo;
>     this.dorsal = dorsal;
>     this.posicion = posicion;
> }
>
> public String getIdjugador() {
>     return idjugador;
> }
>
> public void setIdjugador(String idjugador) {
>     this.idjugador = idjugador;
> }
>
> public String getNombre() {
>     return nombre;
> }
>
> public void setNombre(String nombre) {
>     this.nombre = nombre;
> }
>
> public String getEquipo() {
>     return equipo;
> }
>
> public void setEquipo(String equipo) {
>     this.equipo = equipo;
> }
>
> public String getDorsal() {
>     return dorsal;
> }
>
> public void setDorsal(String dorsal) {
>     this.dorsal = dorsal;
> }
>
> public String getPosicion() {
>     return posicion;
> }
>
> public void setPosicion(String posicion) {
>     this.posicion = posicion;
> }
>
> @Override
> public String toString() {
>     return "Jugador{" + "idjugador=" + idjugador +", nombre=" + nombre + ", equipo=" + equipo + ", dorsal=" + dorsal + ", posicion=" +
> ```
>
> posicion + '}';
> }
>
> }

Thank you!

Comment: try in inicializaFactory to use `em.getMetamodel().entity(Jugador.class);`

Comment: em.getMetamodel().entity(Jugador.class); not working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

JPA requires listing all the entity classes in a [persistence.xml file](https://m.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit), so this is the standard solution to make all the entity classes known in queries even before persisting their first instances.

However, the solution suggested by Panagiotis Bougioukos in a comment should also work (and is simpler), i.e. calling `em.getMetamodel().entity(Jugador.class);` **before** executing the query, on the same database, and then the class becomes also known in queries and the exception should not be thrown.